# How can I create a helper function in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling trying to create a helper function in JS.
My function name is `updateInfo(X);` and it should allow to take in an object.

I have tried

```
var data = {
    "A": {
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "problem_set": "Same",
        "start_time": "7/20/2015 10:00 am",
        "student_am": "9",
        "due_time": "7/20/2015 11:00 am",
        "submit": "9",
        "avg_score": "71",
        "danger": "5",
        "danger_list": "5,10,15,19,23",
        "warning": "8",
        "warning_list": "3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22",
        "success": "12",
        "success_list": "1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"
    },
    "B": {
        "section_num": "2.3",
        "problem_set": "Not the same",
        "start_time": "6/19/2015 1:00 pm",
        "student_am": "23",
        "due_time": "6/19/2015 2:00 pm",
        "submit": "7",
        "avg_score": "82",
        "danger": "10",
        "danger_list": "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20",
        "warning": "10",
        "warning_list": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
        "success": "5",
        "success_list": "21,21,23,24,25"
    }
};


//console.log( data.B.section_num ); // <--- HERE I got 2.3

function updateInfo(X) {
    section_num.html(data.X.section_num);
    problem_set.html(data.X.problem_set);
    start_time.html(data.X.start_time);
    student_am.html(data.X.student_am);
    due_time.html(data.X.due_time);
    submit.html(data.X.submit);
    avg_score.html(data.X.avg_score);
    danger.html(data.X.danger);
    danger_list.html(data.X.danger_list);
    warning.html(data.X.warning);
    warning_list.html(data.X.warning_list);
    success.html(data.X.success);
    success_list.html(data.X.success_list);
}

console.log(updateInfo(B)); // < ---HERE I got error...: (
```

I kept getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: B is not defined

Can someone show me how to fix this ?

What did I forget ?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/kq49u0zv/) - if you guys need it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you call `updateInfo` you should pass it a string so wrap the value in quotes. The error you see is because JS is looking for a variable named `B` which is not available in your code.

```
updateInfo('B');
```

Then, when you access the properties of the `data` object you need to provide the key you passed in as a string using bracket notation:

```
function updateInfo(X) {
    section_num.html(data[X].section_num);
    problem_set.html(data[X].problem_set);
    start_time.html(data[X].start_time);
    student_am.html(data[X].student_am);
    due_time.html(data[X].due_time);
    submit.html(data[X].submit);
    avg_score.html(data[X].avg_score);
    danger.html(data[X].danger);
    danger_list.html(data[X].danger_list);
    warning.html(data[X].warning);
    warning_list.html(data[X].warning_list);
    success.html(data[X].success);
    success_list.html(data[X].success_list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
section_num.html(  data.X.section_num  );
```

and

```
console.log( updateInfo(B) );
```

to

```
section_num.html(  data[X].section_num  );
```

and

```
console.log( updateInfo('B') );
```

The other way could be

```
function updateInfo(ob){
section_num.html(  ob.section_num  );
```

and

```
console.log( updateInfo(data.B) );
```

Comment: So the mistake is I need to put my object around an [ ] - right ?

Comment: the mistake was accessing `B` directly and not as `data.B`

Comment: Ohh I see. and what is the `[ ]` do ?

Comment: `[ ]` can accept the key as string, in short `data.B` is equivalent to `data["B"]`

Comment: Hmm... you should this helpful comments as part of your answer. :)

Comment: actually this for what the comment section can be used.. So you can ask exactly what you didnt understand..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Pass B as a string like so: `updateInfo("B")`.
- And inside the `updateInfo` function, use it like this: `section_num.html(data[X].section_num); ...`.

Comment: You're right about this `updateInfo("B")`- It won't work if it's not in the quote.